# AR / VR Toolkit Reduce Model Mesh to display in AR

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a way to reduce mesh polygons?

As an example project I use the TGA model provided by Autodesk. (https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html   rme_advanced_sample_project.rvt)

If you add all instances to the scene you get a polygon count of about 1.3M.
For the computer this is no problem at all. The model is downloaded in about 1 min and displayed completely.
For my iPhone ( iPhone 8) this is clearly too big.
As soon as I start the AR Scene and download the model, the memory requirement rises to over 1.2 GB (bevore 0,15GB) and crashes the app.

Even if you exclude some instances (walls, ceilings, etc.) before processing the scene to display only the technical building equipment, the model is still too big for the iPhone.

Are there possibilities to reduce the mesh with the ar-vr-toolkit api . Do I have to do this manually in Revit?

Edit: 27.06.18
Here is the model i want to display in AR (Tris: 2.8m, Verts: 2.4M).

Steps:
1) Upload the original .rvt file (70mb) to my bucket.
2) Translated the file via forge.
3) Created a scene with ar-vr-toolkit api.
4) Processed scene witha ar-vr-toolkit api.
5) Downloaded the scene to unity.
6) Created a prefab.

The Meshes are way to detailed. The Graphics would not change a lot if i reduce the Vertex count to 10-15%. 
In Unity i can use assets like Mesh Simplify (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/mesh-simplify-43658) to reduce the count.
An other way is to export the model to e.g. 3D max or Maya to reduce the count.
But i want to try to do this automatically.

My question is: Is there a way to to this with Forge?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS7iR.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3CIv.png)

Answer (score 0):

My colleagues who are expert on this area are on vacation now, so let me try to answer your question first, and my colleague may add some more information later.

Unfortunately, the answer is No AFAIK. For the Forge AR|VR toolkit service, I remember there are some mesh reduction work done automatically at server side if it detect the client device is Hololens or DAQRI, you can get that info if checking https://github.com/wallabyway/ARVRToolkit/blob/master/unity-src/ARVRToolkit/Assets/Forge/ARKit/RequestQueue.cs#L155. But that's it, we do not provide any API to help reduce the mesh, and there is also no API within Forge which can do that either.

As you already know, you may need to do the mesh reduction in some other product, like 3ds Max, that's the current way I can think of.

My colleague may have more comments on this when they come back.

Comment: Just add another comment on this, as confirmed, there is no Mesh Reduction API under Forge AR|VR toolkit service for now, but this is already a known request.